# Best way to save data temporarily in php

Tags: php, sql

I have a some forms that stores data in my page.
I want to find a way to temporarily save the data entered by the user in navigating and keep until the order is confirmed.
Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is exactly what [sessions](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.sessions.php) are for

Comment: sessions are active as long as browser is running. I want to preserve data

Answer (score 2):

While I was working on e-commerce sites we used to keep all the order data
in sessions until user confirms order by going to payment gateway.

You can use PHP Session as arrays and store your data temporary and then destroy the session.

```
 $_SESSION['cart'][] = //you data here
```

Answer (score 1):

Sessions and cookies are used for this purpose but sessions are more secure and reliable.